# how to use Google Map Api in JSP?

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am following the sample code from the Google Map API web page, which uses JavaScript and HTML. The HTML sample works fine, but using JavaScript source in JSP to create Google Maps doesn't work.

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"
    pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is from their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async). How do I use Google Api v3 in JSP Source?

Comment: Put your script tag in the head section and add a div with id 'map-canvas' in the body of your jsp. Make sure this div has some fixed height and width. I hope this will work without any problem.

Comment: @jsjunkie sorry but can't understand your answer :( any sample code there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the code you have posted above is of the jsp you are talking about then you have missed to add the div with id 'map-canvas'. Try something like below.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"
    pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="map-canvas" style="height:300px; width:500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

To render map properly there must be an element to hold it and that element must have a definite height and width. I hope this helps

Comment: Multiple marker is very easy when you declare variable like var marker = new Latlng(..). Make sure there is separate var marker for every pair of lat long otherwise last one will replace all. Please put some code for to the point answer.

Comment: Great stuff. Took me a long time to find this post. Thanks.